# How to cancel the query and show the error if no NULL column found?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have some gimmick table that simulates a shelf with sockets on each rack.

Blank spaces at Reel_ID are NULLs on InnoDB.

```
Rack_ID|Reel_Socket|Reel_ID|Shelf_ID|
-------|-----------|-------|--------|
      1|          1|       |1       |
      1|          2|       |1       |
      1|          3|       |1       |
      2|          1|5      |1       |
      2|          2|6      |1       |
      2|          3|2      |1       |
      2|          4|       |2       |
```

This query "puts" new reel into first possible empty socket that meets requirements.

```
query_update_shelf = 'UPDATE Storage_Table SET Reel_ID = %s WHERE Shelf_ID = %s AND Reel_ID IS NULL LIMIT 1'
```

Then the next query decrements by 1 the Quantity column in another table with according Reel_ID.

All the code logic is here:

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector as mdb
from tkinter import messagebox

query_reel = "SELECT Reel_Manufacturer_ID FROM Delivery_Table WHERE Reel_Manufactuer_ID = %s" 
# this one is kinda redundant because I get Reel_ID from input, Ill delete it later

query_quant = "SELECT Quantity FROM Delivery_Table WHERE Reel_Manufacturer_ID = %s"

'connection here, fetching Reel_ID and Quantity using two cursor.execute'
con = mdb.connect(user=self.user, password=self.pswd, database=self.db)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(query_reel, (reel_input_string,))

reel = cur.fetchall()
reel = reel [0][0]   #  must be a better way

cur.execute(query_quant, (reel__input_string,))

quant = cur.fetchall()
quant = quant[0][0]

shelf_number = 2 # I get shelf_number from a lookup dict actually

if quant != 0:
    quant = quant - 1

    query_update_shelf = 'UPDATE Storage_Table SET Reel_ID = %s WHERE Shelf_ID = %s AND Reel_ID IS NULL LIMIT 1'

    query_update_shelf_to_enter = (reel, shelf_number)

    query_update_quant = 'UPDATE Delivery_Table SET Quantity = %s WHERE Reel_Manufacturer_ID = %s'

    quant_query_values_to_enter = (quant, reel)

    cur.execute(query_update_shelf, query_update_shelf_to_enter)
    cur.execute(query_update_quant, quant_query_values_to_enter)
    con.commit()
    cur.close()

else
   messagebox.showinfo('Query Warning', 'Warning: You have scanned all the reels we have ordered!')
   # there must be an error throw code and some queries not related to the issue
```

So I noticed, if there are no NULL columns with proper Shelf_ID, my query just vanishes into thin air and the Quantity still gets decremented, basically resulting in a loss.

How can I work around this?

Comment: i don't see any code where the qiantity increased or decreased for that matter

Comment: @nbk that's just some boring checks. It doesn't look pretty in comments though.

```if quant != 0:

   quant = quant - 1

   query_update_quant 
```

if quant is 0, throw an error and delete the row.

Comment: you can always check the affected rows and then decrease the number if > 0. but without complete code i can't write you an answer

Comment: @nbk I edited my post and added all the code, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as is aid in the column you can check th affected rows with rowcount.

and only update the second query if some rows got changed

```
quant_query_values_to_enter = (quant, reel)

cur.execute(query_update_shelf, query_update_shelf_to_enter)
if cur.rowcount > 0:
    cur.execute(query_update_quant, quant_query_values_to_enter)
con.commit()
cur.close()
```